# MongoDB RegExp inconsistency

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

Here's the test case:

```
db.test.insert({ name: "john"});
db.test.insert({ name: "donny"});
db.test.insert({ name: "lenny"});

db.test.find({ name: { $regex: /^((?!nn)[\s\S])*$/}}); //works fine, returns only john
db.test.find({ name: { $regex: new RegExp("/^((?!nn)[\s\S])*$/")}}); //returns nothing
```

The regex is supposed to return objects that are not containg "nn" but it doesn not work when using RegExp object. I tested this using Robomongo.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include the leading and trailing `/` characters when using `new RegExp`.  Those are only used with the literal notation in JavaScript.  You also need to escape your backslashes in the string.

```
db.test.find({ name: { $regex: new RegExp("^((?!nn)[\\s\\S])*$")}});
```